# Windows Server 2012 local policy settings through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I am working on automating group policy settings using PowerShell in Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have lot of local group policy settings to achieve through PowerShell. 
 As an example I am showing this

> Press Windows key > type Run and type gpedit.msc. Expand Computer
>   Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings >
>   Account Policy > Password Policy or Account Lockout Policy container

In this I need to enable the setting called Passwords Must Meet Complexity Requirements using PowerShell.

I achieved automating services start-up type using the cmdlets. 
As an example

```
Set-Service -name vds -StartupType disabled
```

But I am struggling to start with local group policy settings.
I have also attached a screenshot regarding this.

If anyone have any idea on this Please help me.

Comment: Group Policy is mostly just registry values and [you can use PowerShell to modify those values](http://serverfault.com/questions/625901/can-i-use-powershell-to-configure-local-group-policy-settings-in-windows-server).

Comment: Why are you trying to take settings that are set reliably and consistently through group policy and apply them via a script?

Comment: I have more than five hundred of local group policy settings to apply, If I don't have PowerShell script for achieving this functionality ,I need to do this manually on my dev, QA and production servers.